# MooEditable doesn't POST textarea value

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        $('tresc_wiecej').mooEditable({
            actions: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | formatBlock justifyleft justifyright justifycenter justifyfull | insertunorderedlist insertorderedlist indent outdent insertHorizontalRule | undo redo removeformat | createlink unlink | urlimage | toggleview'
        });
</script>
<form id="theForm" action="?a=send_news" method="post">
    <label>Title: </label>
    <input type="text" name="title"></input>

    <label>Text:</label>
    <textarea  name="text" id="tresc_wiecej" >
    ss
    </textarea>

    <label>Tags: </label>
    <input type="text" name="tag"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

PHP

```
if ($_GET['a'] == "send_news")
{
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $tag=$_POST['tag'];
    $text=$_POST['text'];
}
```

And I can receive without any problems values: tag, title, but textarea is empty even when i used some default value (ss).

Solution:

To script add:

```
    function getData()
{

 document.getElementById('hid').value = $(tresc_wiecej').mooEditable().getContent();
}
```

Full script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        $('tresc_wiecej').mooEditable({
            actions: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | formatBlock justifyleft justifyright justifycenter justifyfull | insertunorderedlist insertorderedlist indent outdent insertHorizontalRule | undo redo removeformat | createlink unlink | urlimage | toggleview'
        });

        function getData()
    {

     document.getElementById('hid').value = $(tresc_wiecej').mooEditable().getContent();
    }

</script>
```

To form add hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hid" id="hid">
```

To submit button add action getData() on click:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="getData()" value="Send">
```

Full form:

```
<form id="theForm" action="?a=send_news" method="post">
    <label>Title: </label>
    <input type="text" name="title"></input>

    <label>Text:</label>
    <textarea  name="text" id="tresc_wiecej" >

    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid" id="hid">

    <label>Tags: </label>
    <input type="text" name="tag"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And PHP

```
$text=$_POST['hid'];
```

Comment: Please show us the php part, where you try to access the posted values.

Comment: Ok, first post updated.

Comment: What about a jsfiddle for the JS part ?

Comment: The php code looks good. Please follow @challets lead and create a jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cheeaun/NHBVa/ - this is jsfiddle from example page, i haven't changed anything from there.

Just copy paste from example he attached to his release.

When i press submit alert msg works, i see html code from wyswig editor, even when i use his example to post value of textare then example page is able to retrieve them.

Comment: fiddle of your own context please :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K8HwX/1/ Here You go :)

Comment: please try putting `print_r($_POST)` check what you get in post...

Comment: Array ( [title] => ssaa [tag] => aa )
It's something with mooeditables, because when i use simple textarea it works.

Comment: try putting `# hash` before `tresc_wiecej` in your script,.. `$('#tresc_wiecej').mooEditable`

Comment: If i do it WYSWIG  editor won't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        $('textarea-1').mooEditable();

       // Post submit
        $('theForm').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        alert($('textarea-1').value);
        return true;
    });
});
```

```
<form id="theForm" method="post" action="">
    <label for="textarea-1">Textarea 1 (try paste copied text!)</label>
    <textarea id="textarea-1" name="editable1"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry.. I have made one mistake.. I have edited it.. I have put `value="hid"` but it should be `id="hid"`.. try it...

Comment: I've noticed :) I added id and still it doesn't work. When i remove value then value is empty after POST.

Comment: try `alerting data`.. does it return something

Comment: [Object HTMLDivElement] and data.value = undefined

Comment: strange.. as its `docs` says it should return string.. https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/blob/master/Docs/MooEditable/MooEditable.md

Comment: Still doesn't send textarea value which appears in alertbox

Comment: Ok! Got it :) I mixed Your idea with replacing value by js (GetData).
   function getData()
{

 document.getElementById('hid').value = $('textarea-1').mooEditable().getContent();
}

Comment: yeah.. I was just suppose to say that... enjoy :)

Comment: Should i post full solution?

Comment: Well i can't reply so fast, so here is the link if u would like edit Your post with answer.
http://pastebin.com/ECrzgi8W